# SWRevealViewController with UISplitViewController gesture not triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I use `SWRevealViewController` and `UISplitViewController`. 
So what is happening: 
(I have now 3 `UIViewController`: menu, mainList and detail view on the right side) The mainList moves to the right showing the menu and overlaying the detail view(a bit). Now when I want to close the menu by touching (dragging) the mainList, half of the area of menuList is not touchable, the touches are redirected to detailView (which is under the mainList). 
Please help me, i'm a newbie in `iOS`

I would show some sceenshots, but the system doesn't allow me...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#import "SWRevealViewController.h"` in your mainListViewController and add this in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, your answer almost solved the problem, but now the menu another two viewControllers have lost the recogniser...

Comment: You set this code only in your mainList. Make sure your other viewControllers' class are not same as your mainList.

Comment: Also, you can use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to manage multiple gestures in your tableview.